# Help with Formula Field - IF & LEFT Functions

Tags: apex, formula, formula-field, if, salesforce-functions

Newbie here. Would appreciate all your help.

I'm trying to write a formula for the following Scenario:
Field Name - "Course Interest" has Certificate I, Certificate II, Certificate III, Certificate IV and Diploma in relevant cohorts e.g. Certificate IV in Engineering.  I have to create a formula field (Course Level) that will output value as below:
Certificate I - Level 1
Certificate II - Level 2
Certificate III - Level 3
Certificate IV- Level 4
Diploma - Level 5

I have the code as below but for Certificate I, II, III and IV it gives the same values for all.

```
IF
(LEFT(Course_Interest_c,13) = "Certificate I", 
    "Level 1", 

 IF(
        LEFT(Course_Interest_c,14) = "Certificate II", 
        "Level 2", 
     

  IF(
           LEFT(Course_Interest_c,15) = "Certificate III", 
            "Level 3", 

      IF(
                LEFT(Course_Interest_c,13) = "Certificate IV", 
                "Level 4",
             IF(
                    LEFT(Course_Interest_c,7) = "Diploma", 
                    "Level 5",
                    "Not Relevant"
                )
            )
        )))
```

Comment: field `Course_Interest_c` is text field?

Comment: And can you tried `Case`? Ref: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_case.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're hitting here is that with the order in which you're evaluating the values, the first check for 'Certificate I' is always going to be true for the other values.

To fix this, you could simply evaluate these in the opposite order, i.e. check from Diploma down to Certificate I.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. This worked